# Why does my collada DAE character has a green face on Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, collada

I have a DAE character that looks correct (better actually) in Unity, but when I put it to Xcode her face turns green and neck is yellow. I don't think it is misplaced because I can see her eyes, nose, mouth and ears but her face is green for some reason.

[image]

Weird thing is, in Finder's preview, it also has a green face

[image]

Please help because other characters look fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your model has a corrupted UV texture set. When this model was texturing in Unity, facial UV texture set was occasionally deleted or corrupted. A solution is simple – go to `Unity UV Editor`, select facial UV vertices of your model and reassign texture.

In Xcode you can only **`assign`** a texture and not fix UV texture set, because Xcode has no UV Texture Editor. So there's no available solution for Xcode, because it's not a texture's issue, it's UVs' issue.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that will fix when I put it in Xcode, not in Unity

Comment: Xcode has no UV Texture Editor. There's no solution in Xcode. All models are UV-textured in 3D authoring software like Maya, 3dsMax, Blender, Unity, etc.

Comment: I downloaded Unity and added UV Editor, and it is showing the face properly, but I dont see a way to update the texture

Comment: The solution is simple. In Unity, at first save a UV-texture in a file, then delete a UV-texture from a model, assign a new shader (Lambert, for example) and assign a texture again from scratch. That's all.